# Setting classpth in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, classpath

I have Simple java program named MainController.java. Wehn I try to compile it from the directory where I have stored my MainController.java file by writing javac MAinController.java, it compiles properly and generates MainController.class file in  the same directory. Now 
1) when I try to run the file by writing "java MainController", it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MainController (wrong name: cased/test/MainController)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    Could not find the main class: MainController. Program will exit.
    ragini@ragini-ThinkPad-W500:~/workspace/Test/src/cased/test$
```

I know there is some problem with my classpath. How do I set ? I want that when I run command "java MainController" from the directory where there is Maincontroller.class file, it should run it. I dont want to pass -cp parameter to java command each time I want to run it.

For jvm info I ran "java -version" and it displays following:

java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.6) (6b22-1.10.6-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Please tell me how to set classpath variable and what it to set for above jvm.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the package name when you execute `MainController`.  From your `~workspace/Test/src` directory, execute the following:

```
javac cased/test/MainController.java
java cased.test.MainController
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set the -cp flag each time, you can use the CLASSPATH environment variable.
but you probably want to set this variable up to your common jars directory (like you lib directory and src in your project).

Anyway, it's seems like the problem is that you need to set the full class name- package+class,
for example for the class MAinController that is in org.examples package you should use:
javac org.examples.MAinController 
from the main directory of your project

Comment: and if I want to specify classpath environment variale, how do I do that ? I mean could pl tell me the syntax ? and where to write it ?

Comment: export CLASSPATH="/home/user/project/lib:/home/usr/project/src"